# Sort by first element in an array mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, cursor

I have many documents in my mongodb and I have one fields named `images` which is an array, users can add up to 3 image urls in that array.

It would look like this:

```
{
 images: ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
 ...restOfDocument
}
```

I want to sort documents only by the first element in array, if it exists, I just want to sort all the documents asc or desc if there is at least one url in that array.

I tried:

```
{
  images: -1/1 OR  "images.0": -1/1
}
```

None of the above worked, I don't want to use aggregate, I just want to know if there is a way to do it using cursor sort from MongoDb.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if arrays are empty

Comment: If there are 2 docs, one with an array with 1 item and a doc with an empty array, the empty array should be last/first depending on the sorting

Comment: hmm doesnt that happens with the normal sort({"images.0":1/-1})

Comment: It does not work, it takes into consideration the other elements that are in that array too, for example, if a doc has 2 elements in an array it will appear before another doc that has only one element...I tried it a few times with that solution

Comment: `db.collection.find({}).sort({"images.0":-1})` is working for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 3 sample documents:

```
[
  {images: ["url1", "url2", "url3"]},
  {images: ["url7", "url2"]},
  {images: []}
]
```

With a simple sorting:

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({"images.0":-1})
```

returns:

```
[
  {images: ["url7", "url2"]},
  {images: ["url1", "url2", "url3"]},
  {images: []}
]
```

As expected

Comment: Thank you for being my rubber duck, turns out there was something wrong with my code.